# How to remove newrelic when installed using .sh script?

Tags: newrelic

I followed the onboarding instructions:

```
 curl -Ls https://download.newrelic.com/install/newrelic-cli/scripts/install.sh | bash && sudo  NEW_RELIC_API_KEY=xxxxxx NEW_RELIC_ACCOUNT_ID=3964531 /usr/local/bin/newrelic install
```

How do i uninstall it?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command to stop the New Relic daemon if it is currently running:

```
sudo newrelic infra stop
```

Next, run the uninstallation command:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/newrelic uninstall
```